# Adding text removes textview format

Tags: ios, xcode, textview, format

Whenever I add text to my textview in xcode all the formatting disappears. My textview settings look like this:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/28clzrb.jpg

When I run the app, I get the desired format as seen in this image:

http://s8.postimg.org/c8c33c9p1/bild_1_1.png

However, when this line of code is added:

```
self.addressLabel.text = @"123";
```

The format goes away and the textview now looks like this:

http://postimg.org/image/b0p1oxa6b/

My only guess is that the format is somehow present in the NSString and overwrites what is currently in the textview, but that does not seem to be the case as this code also removes all the formatting:

```
self.addressLabel.text = [self.addressLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"123"];
```

Why is the formatting removed, has anyone got a clue?

Comment: I noticed this too in iOS7. It only does, when the textView.selectable = NO. It is fixed in iOS8.

Comment: Wow, that's super weird. Anyhow my problem is fixed, thank you!